# Change color of text in cells within brackets

Tags: vba, excel

I have cells in a sheet that include a bunch of text, but also have certain text within square brackets that look like this:

> [Assign: some text here]
>
> [Select: some text here]

I need a macro that will change the color of any text starting with Assign to green (including Assign) and any text starting with Select to blue (also including Select). Brackets themselves could be color changed or not, whatever is easiest.

I have tried multiple ways to do this but cannot figure out with a regex or a replace how to do this. Closest I have come was uppercasing all text within [] brackets but not making a distinction between Assign or Select.

Appreciate the help

Edit:

What I have so far:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim m As Object
    Dim test As Range
    Dim strInput As String
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "\[(.*?)\]"
        For Each r In Range("C2:C2")
            If .test(r.Value) Then
                For Each m In .Execute(r.Value)
                    r.Value = Replace(r.Value, m.Value, UCase(m.Value))
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show what you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range(SomeRange).Characters(start,length).Font.Color = vbGreen
```

To get your start and length, use `Instr`

```
start = Instr(1, Range(SomeRange).Value, "[Assign", vbTextCompare)
length = Instr(start, Range(SomeRange).Value, "]", vbTextCompare) - start + 1
```

If `start` is zero then string not found.

--

***UPDATE:***

Off top of my head, for multiple instances in the same cell:

```
start = 1

Do

    start = Instr(start, Range(SomeRange).Value, "[Assign", vbTextCompare)

    If start > 0 Then

        length = Instr(start, Range(SomeRange).Value, "]", vbTextCompare) - start + 1

        if length > 1 then Range(SomeRange).Characters(start, length).Font.Color = vbGreen

        start = start + length

    End If

Loop While start > 0
```

Comment: One more level of error control if you use `length = Instr(start,...` for the second one. It will still return the position from the begining, not from where *start* is.

Comment: This seems to work! What would be the easiest way to put this in a loop? Sometimes I have multiple of these bracket statements per cell. (My excel VBA is really crap)